# each do if not nil - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an invoices model that has a paid boolean attribute.  There's an association between accounts and invoices and I'd like to show only unpaid invoices in a view.

I'm using this to show all invoices:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Invoice Number</th>
      <th>Invoice Date</th>
      <th>Invoice Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @account.invoices.each do |invoice| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= invoice.id%> </td>
        <td><%= invoice.created_at.time.to_formatted_s(:long)%> Zulu </td>
        <td><%= invoice.total %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

But I'm unsure how to limit results to where only invoices where `paid` is nil will be shown.  I tried: `<% @account.invoices.each do |invoice| unless @account.invoices.paid == 'nil' %>`, but hit errors.  Obviously I'm getting my syntax wrong. Any advice?

Comment: Not sure, maybe try `@account.invoices.select do |invoice| invoice.nil? end`

Comment: @Atul Khanduri's answer is the "Rails way" of solving this problem – you should definitely do it that way. Just for the record though, the 'skip iteration of a block under certain conditions' syntax you were looking for would be conditional use of `next` – for example, you could put `next if invoice.paid.nil?` as the first line of your `each` block.

Comment: @omnikron Thanks for the info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`named scope`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) in this case.

Created an `unpaid` scope in `invoices` model:

```
scope :unpaid, -> { where( paid: [nil, false] ) }
```

And use that in views, like this:

```
<% @account.invoices.unpaid.each do |invoice| %>
```

Comment: Great - should have thought of that.  Works great, thanks!

Comment: @PSCampbell ... Your's welcome. I think you forgot to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer, a SO way to say thanks. ;)

Comment: It was on a time delay, got it now!